# The snapshot is masked, not in raw colors

Tags: linux, gnome, snapshot, screenshot

I capture screen using `gnome-screenshot 3.18.0`.

When we select the region to capture, the region is masked and becomes blue.

When saving to picture files, the snapshot is expected to be back to raw colors, but it doesn't, as in this picture.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: do you have `compiz` installed on your ubuntu machine ?

Comment: hi, @Rahul , I have `compiz`, `metacity` and `mutter`. But I have no idea which one is in use.

Comment: can you please disable Ubuntu Unity Plugin and try again ?

Comment: @Rahul In `ccsm`, `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` is disabled

Comment: I tried to enable it, but there were a lot of conflicts, so I stopped.